# Как записывать введенное сообщение пользователем в базу данных (pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть код, который работает и переносит сообщение пользователя в базу данных, но не совсем тот что, нужен:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['name'])
def nickname(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя')
        db.update_nickname(message.from_user.id, message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Имя успешно задано!')
```

SQL запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
def update_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `nickname` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (nickname, user_id))
```

В моем примере он заносит в ячейку "nickname" базы данных значение '/name' так как handler вызван на данную команду. Как мне заносить туда значение которое пользователь введет с клавиатуры после сообщения "Введите имя".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для получения "аргумента" команды можно использовать split(maxsplit=1):

```
message.text.split(maxsplit=1)
[In]: /name тест
[Out]: ['name', 'тест']

message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
>> тест
```

либо используйте [bot.register_next_step_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['name'])
def nickname(message):
     msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя')
     bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, nickname_2)


def nickname_2(message):
     db.update_nickname(message.from_user.id, message.text)
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Имя успешно задано!')
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ является решением вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его таковым. Это поможет другим пользователям.